# Error using oracle sequence in php

Tags: php, oracle, oracle11g

Every time when I'm running the following PHP code I'm getting output

**Booking Confirmed! Congratulation. Your Booking Id is: 6**

for successful booking.

The bookingid is a sequence and then I'm getting that booking id form the inserted values to get the current value of the sequence. So I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

```
   <html><body>
   <?php
       $con = oci_connect("system", "password", "localhost/XE");
          if (!$con) {
            $m = oci_error();
        exit('Connect Error ' . $m['message']);
        }
        $thid = $_GET["hid"];
        $trno = $_GET["rno"];
        $tgid = $_GET["gid"];
        $sd = $_GET["sdate"];
        $ed = $_GET["edate"];
        $dchange = "ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT= 'YYYY-MM-DD'";
        $stid1 = oci_parse($con,$dchange);
        oci_execute($stid1);
        $c1 = "SELECT * FROM B WHERE HOTELID = '$thid' AND ROOMNO = '$trno' AND ((STARTDATE < '$sd' AND ENDDATE > '$sd') or (STARTDATE < '$ed' AND ENDDATE > '$ed') or (STARTDATE >= '$sd' AND ENDDATE <= '$ed'))";
        $c2 = oci_parse($con, $c1);
        oci_execute($c2);
        $row = oci_fetch_row($c2);
        if(!$row)
        {
        $temp =  "INSERT INTO B VALUES(bno.nextval,'$thid','$trno','$tgid','$sd','$ed')";
        $stid = oci_parse($con,$temp);
        oci_execute($stid);
         oci_free_statement($stid);
        //$c7 = "SELECT bookid FROM B WHERE HOTELID = '$thid' AND ROOMNO = '$trno' AND GUEStID = '$tgid' AND STARTDATE = '$sd' AND ENDDATE = '$ed'";
        //printf("<h3>Booking Confirmed! Congatulation. </h3>") ;
        **$c8 = oci_parse($con, "SELECT MAX(BOOKID) FROM B");
        oci_execute($c8);
        printf("<h3>Booking Confirmed! Congratulation. Your Booking Id is: %u</h3>", $c8);**
        }
        else
            printf("<h3>Booking already exist. </br>Please try with another search.</h3>");


        ?>
</n> <form action="index.php"><input type="submit" value="BACK" />
    </form>

</BODY>
```

Answer (score 0):

a few suggestions for you.

1. you should be using [bind variables](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) and not splicing literals in your SQL statements (unless you want the performance of your DB to degrade as you fill the shared pool up).
2. `SELECT MAX(BOOKID) FROM B` is the wrong and unsafe way to get the booking id. as if 2 sessions in parallel made a booking, you could get wrong results (you can also get wrong results if the max id in the table is higher than the current sequence value). instead do `select bno.currval from dual` or use the [returning clause](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/returninginto_clause.htm) as part of the insert (assuming PHP works with that)
3. on your insert you should specify the column names for good practice . i.e do `INSERT INTO B (BOOKID, HOTELID, ROOMNO, STARTDATE, ENDDATE) VALUES(bno.nextval....`

Comment: I don't have any parallel booking.. but still I'm not getting the the correct bookingid. First I tried bno.currval but even that was not working so thought of trying other way. But no change in the output. There is some problem in that part where I'm trying to retrieve the bookingid. Because if I check my booking table it's inserted correctly.

Comment: @HarshShah where is the `oci_fetch_row` for the max(bookid) though? you seem to be printing the statement handle ID `$c8` vs the fetched row value

Comment: Thank you Dazzal for figuring out where I was goin wrong. Thanks it worked.